# How can I allow for image insertion via URL but not uploading?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and I want to allow people to place images by using a URL, but *not* upload.  I can't figure out how to accomplish that.  My toolbar is:

```
toolbar: {
    items: [
        'heading','|','bold','italic','link','bulletedList','numberedList','|','indent','outdent','alignment','|','HorizontalLine','ImageInsert','BlockQuote','InsertTable','MediaEmbed','Undo','Redo','|','FontColor','FontSize','Strikethrough','Subscript','Superscript'
    ]
},
```

Originally it had 'ImageUpload', so I removed that thinking it would work yet the image icon for ImageInsert, when clicked directly, opens the browser file dialog for an upload.  You have to hit the down arrow to get the URL.  What should I change it to such that clicking the icon opens the URL dialog directly?

Thanks!

PS, I inherited this, I didn't make it initially and as such I have no idea what version of CK it is nor how to determine that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
....
config.removePlugins = 'easyimage, cloudservices';
....
};
```

Then click on image tab on Editor and insert your Image Url In Url Field

Comment: Hmm.  My implementation has no CKEDITOR available, the var I use to set it up is ClassicEditor.  I tried using that code swapping ClassicEditor for CKEDITOR and it throws no error, but causes no change in the behavior.  Does using ClassicEditor mean I have to approach it differently?